# Laravel problema con helper route()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vistas, router

En el javascript de mi vista blade tengo:

```
$('#miSelector').on('change', function () {
    // .... Más código
    if (condicion) {
        $('#miFormulario').prop('action', "{{ route('nombre_de_ruta') }}");
    } else {
        $('#miFormulario').prop('action', "{{ route('otro_nombre_de_ruta') }}");
    }
    $('#miFormulario').submit();
});
```

Esto funciona perfectamente. Cuando se dispara el evento, elige la ruta adecuada, y el formulario es dirigido al controlador deseado.

El problema viene cuando coloco este javascript en un archivo externo, en `public/js`, y lo llamo desde el blade, con el helper `asset()`, así:

```
<script language="javascript" src="{{ asset('js/mi_script.js') }}"></script>
```

Todo el script funciona bien (he puesto `console.log` para ir viendo el estado de las variables, y trazarlo todo), excepto el helper `route()`, que ya no puede resolver la ruta, y genera unos caracteres que "corrompen" la URL, llevándome a un 404. He probado sustituyendo

```
"{{ route('otro_nombre_de_ruta') }}"
```

por

```
"{!! route('otro_nombre_de_ruta') !!}"
```

pero tampoco funciona.

Esto me ocurre en ambos casos (si se cumple el condicional, como si no). Es como si el helper `route()` no pudiera funcionar en scripts externos que se importan a la vista, si no que tuviera que estar físicamente dentro de la vista.

Existe alguna solución, o estoy enfocando mal el planteamiento? En cualquier caso, si pudiérais darme una respuesta clara y detallada (aún soy muy novata con Laravel), os lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás confundiendo el procesamiento en el servidor y en el cliente (navegador en este caso):

Cuando llamas a un archivo externo de JavaScript (En este caso), Laravel no lo lee o importa o similar, puesto que ya estás en el navegador, lo que haces con el helper `asset()` es simplemente definir la ruta del archivo externo.

Tu archivo `mi_script.js` es interpretado por el navegador como cualquier otro archivo de JavaScript de cualquier sitio web, y por consiguiente no va a «encontrar» nunca la ruta de Laravel.

**Soluciones**

Antes que nada, Laravel no está diseñado para trabajar de esa manera, está fuera de su alcance.

Depende de cómo esté diseñada tu aplicación, puedes utilizar [Laroute](https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute) para tener tus rutas disponibles en JavaScript (pero debes tener en cuenta qué rutas habilitas), o puedes buscar la forma de retornar dicha sección de JavaScript a tu vista blade. Hay algunas otras soluciones pero todas resultan siendo externas a Laravel.