# Laravel - Route dentro de JS

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-7, laravel-8

Intento hacer una función en JS que dado un parámetro construya una URl de forma dinámica, el código que tengo es este

```
<script>

function cargar_datos(estado) {

    alert(estado);
    
    var uri =  '{{ route('api.cars.list', ['estado' => ':estado']) }}';
    uri = uri.replace(':estado',estado);

    alert(uri);

    $('#tabla-listado-leads').bootstrapTable('refresh', {
        url: uri
    });

}
```

El primer alert (estado) me muestra por pantalla un "2"

Pero el segundo alert que es uri me muestra :
http://test.local/api/cars/list?estado=%3Aestado

Lo que intento construir es una url que sea
http://test.local/api/cars/list?estado=2

Usando el helper route de laravel.

La ruta la tengo declarada de esta forma

```
Route::get('/api/cars/list', 'CarController@listCars')->name('api.cars.list');
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Laravel problema con helper route()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/242833/laravel-problema-con-helper-route)

Comment: Gracias, intento hacerlo sin ningún paquete extra.

Comment: Amigo, ¿puedes hacer un `console.log(uri)` justo antes de usar el `replace()` y decirme que te sale? recuerda que la sintaxis de `{{ }}` usa la función [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php) de **PHP** y puede no estarte pasando lo que deseas con `:` los dos puntos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente

```
var uri =  '{{ route('api.cars.list', ['estado' => ':estado']) }}';
uri = uri.replace(new RegExp(':estado','g'),estado);
```

Comment: Lo he probado y me produce la misma salida.

Comment: He añadido el post principal como tengo declarada la ruta, por si afecta en algo.

Comment: Si afecta, la sintaxis que te he puesto es para cuando tienes `Route::get('/api/cars/list/{estado}', 'CarController@listCars')->name('api.cars.list');`

Comment: tienes razón. Gracias tema zanjado. 1000 gracias a todos/as

Answer (score 1):

Todo tu problema son las `"` y las `'`

Asi, funciona:

```
var uri =  "{{ route('api.leads.list', 'estado') }}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he solucionado de esta forma.

No es muy elegante...pero funciona. Mientras encuentro una forma mejor.

```
    var uri =  '{{ route('api.leads.list', "estado") }}';
    uri = uri.replace('estado','estado=' + estado);

    console.log(uri);
```

Comment: Échale un ojo a mi comentario, creo que ese era tu problema